# 30K record list response for JSON in angular2

Tags: java, angularjs, json, angular2-services

Hi I am trying to send List of object from Java controller to Angular in JSON. If the result is 20000 it is working fine. But in case of 30000 angular is getting empty body. Can any one help regarding how to get this 30000 record at 1 time. Angular service getting data and converting from JSON
        Java Code return:
        List<**VO>

```
     private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json(); -- Error body is coming - ""
        let data = body || [];
        return data;
      }
```

Comment: probably not a good idea to fetch that many records at the same time. Might get a timeout or a whole host of other problems. Also...

show some more code, we need to see the java bit as well.

Comment: donno why it breaks. but @yılmaz got a really good point. probably its better to implement "paging" and loop through it  for such load

Comment: you might have timeout error on the server

Comment: Well the first question you need to ask yourself. Why do you need a list of 30k items in your browser? Angular isn't build for that amount of items especially if you have some binding on the list.  I think it is the amount of data that can be serialized is the problem. But seriously look at your architecture if you have this much data on your website.

Comment: Yes, We have that much data and need to display at angular. i am doing pagination. But when user click on Last button I am calling next set of result and merging in previous list. which result overwriting of previous result. Using Pagination http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google

Comment: if(page === 1000 && this.rerunflag != false){
    this.startIndex = '20002';
      this.endIndex = String(this.maxResult);
      this.pagedItems = [];
    this.ngOnInit();
   }

Comment: @Gourav i realy don't believe that you need that much data on a page. There is no one  that will scroll to the complete list. Just ask your interaction designer

Comment: please edit your question with this kind of data so you can format it as code or add an answer to your own question with the code in it. This is unreadable..

Comment: @Gourav `Pagination` is done with the back end. You only load that part of the data from the server that you want to display. I think what you currently are trying is to load all data to the front end and the do a  "fake" `Pagination` only with the front end

Comment: Thanks for idea. Doing pagination at front and back end which is working fine. This is just to check if some where I am missing any angular functionality to get this much data.

Answer (score 1):

There's hardly ever a good reason to load all the data in the front end with large datasets as it causes a lot of problems and generally makes your web application slow. You're doing pagination, but you're doing it only in the front end. Pagination can also be done in the back end. Instead of getting ALL items from the back end and handling pagination solely on the front end, you should only fetch all data for the current page from the back end. Extend your API with a page number and page size and make the API return the count for the total number of results as well either as part of the response body or in an HTTP header. Each time a user changes to a different page you request the data for that particular page again from the back end.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can get records partially, like 10000 record from single request. Then merge the records on javascript side.